# Unable to merge two DataFrame. ( TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() )

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using StackOverflow's survey data to analyze which can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QOmVDpd8hcVYqqUXDXf68UMDWQZP0wQV).

Now, I have a data frame **clear_df** after dropping NaN and resetting the index from the original data frame  as

```
  index DevType ConvertedComp
0   2   Designer;Developer, back-end;Developer, front-...   8820.0
1   3   Developer, full-stack   61000.0
2   5   Data or business analyst;Data scientist or mac...   366420.0
3   8   Database administrator;Developer, back-end;Dev...   95179.0
4   9   Data or business analyst;Data scientist or mac...   13293.0
```

So, I have used the split function to form a new data frame with split 'DevType' as **temp12**.

temp12 can be seen below.

```
level_0 level_1 0
0   0   0   Designer
1   0   1   Developer, back-end
2   0   2   Developer, front-end
3   0   3   Developer, full-stack
4   1   0   Developer, full-stack
5   2   0   Data or business analyst
```

Now, I want to merge the 'ConvertedComp' from **clean_df** to **temp12** using **level_0** column of temp12 as index of **clean_df**.

**Expected Output**

```
level_0 level_1 0                         ConvertedComp
    0   0   0   Designer                  8820.0
    1   0   1   Developer, back-end       8820.0
    2   0   2   Developer, front-end      8820.0
    3   0   3   Developer, full-stack     8820.0
    4   1   0   Developer, full-stack     61000.0
    5   2   0   Data or business analyst  366420.0
```

But I am getting an error as

> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

You can run the below code to replicate the error by downloading dataset from here [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QOmVDpd8hcVYqqUXDXf68UMDWQZP0wQV):

```
df_2019 = pd.read_csv("dataset/developer_survey_2019/survey_results_public.csv")

def split_column_value(ori_df, column_name, separator=';'):
    '''
    INPUT - ori_df  - pandas dataframe -  original dataframe
            column_name - string - the name of the column you would like to splite the value
            separator - string - The is a delimiter. The string splits at this specified separator. If is not provided then ; is the separator.
    OUTPUT - 
            df - pandas dataframe - all value for the column of original dataframe
    '''
    ori_df = ori_df.dropna(subset=['DevType','ConvertedComp'])
    df = pd.DataFrame(ori_df[column_name].str.split(separator).tolist()).stack()
    return df

# splite the DevType colume value
temp1 = split_column_value(df_2019, 'DevType')

temp12 = pd.DataFrame(temp1).reset_index()
temp12.head(20)

clean_df=df_2019.dropna(subset=['DevType','ConvertedComp']).reset_index()[['DevType','ConvertedComp']]
clean_df

# LINE WHICH THROWS THE ERROR
merge_df = temp12.merge(clean_df, right_index=True, right_on='ConvertedComp')
```

Comment: Yes, your question is a bit confusing - but you can change that! Provide us a small sample which we can run easily on our computers but still reproduces the same error that you get. I.e. remove everything from your code but the line which throws the error and then you make a small code example out of it. Then you'll see that you'll can ask a much better (less confusing) question to us.

Comment: Hey, @mrzo thanks for the suggestions and I have edited my code and I am sorry it can be that small only to replicate the error. Though you can directly run in your system after importing pandas.